# Meaning of & in an insert statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

Suppose i am having a table employee with 2 columns emp_ID and e_name and i normally insert the rows in the table as   "insert into employee values('some_value', 'some_vale')" but somewhere i saw the insert statement as "insert into employee(&emp_ID, '&e_name')"  emp_ID is number type and e_name of varchar.  MY QUESTION: what is the use of & in insert statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably a sqlplus script - & is the variable substitution character

[Have a look here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/515)

Comment: is the sql we use in oracle 10g different from sqlplus script?

Comment: sqlplus is the command line tool that connects to oracle. It's different from an application you write. At the command line type sqlplus and it should start up.

Comment: thanks daven11 i never knew that.....But is there any benefit of doing all SQL related work at sqlplus instead of working directly with the Oracle 10g software?

Comment: not sure what you mean? sqlpllus is a command line tool for ad hoc querying, and scripting. I use it a lot for running sql scripts in batches on Unix. Oracle 10g is a database server - there is no real way of working directly with it - all communications is done by applications either server or client side. sqlplus is one of those applications. If that answers your question?

Comment: What i mean is that i have Oracle 10g Xpress edition install and i can easily write, exexute queries in Oracle 10g, by going to the database homepage, filling the username and password and then have the option of using the Object Browser or Sql drop down box to select sql command and finally enter commands. IN SHORT WITHOUT USING THE COMMAND PROMPT. Hope i am clear

Comment: OK, and that is a web interface (if it's what I'm thinking of), and in the background there's a web server that takes the sql you've typed in and runs it on the database server and returns the results. sqlplus is a command line version which does the same sort of thing. Both are different ways to access the database. One thing to remember is that Oracle is a *server* which means that all your applications talk to the server via the oracle API's. I'm not sure of your background so excuse me if somethings seem obvious. A server forks processes and does a lot of stuff to support multi user.

Answer (score 4):

They are called Input variables.

You should take a look at this article: http://www.orafaq.com/node/515

Answer (score 2):

& is a special character which causes the statement to wait for an input

Comment: create table emp( e_id integer, e_name varchar(50))

select * from emp

insert into emp values(&e_id ,'&e_name');        I am getting an error "Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '&'.
"